# How can I get a row with two columns and a row with one column using MUI Grid?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I wonder how I can achieve the design shown in the image with MUI components.

[image]

My problem is that I don't know how to insert the third Button into the MUI grid so it has the same width compared to the two other buttons.

```
<Container>
  <Grid
    container
    direction="row"
    justifyContent="flex-start"
    alignItems="center"
    spacing={4}
  >
    <Grid item>
      <Button variant="outlined" onClick={() => {}}>
        Button 1
      </Button>
    </Grid>

    <Grid item>
      <Button color="secondary" variant="contained" onClick={() => {}}>
        Button 2
      </Button>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Container>
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: You haven't given your grid items width attributes. Have you read [the docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/#basic-grid)? They make it pretty clear how that's done. You simply need two half-width columns (6 units) and a full-width column (12 units).

Answer (score 1):

Check this tutorial: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/

Should look something like this:

```
<Grid container spacing={2}>
  <Grid item xs={6}>
    BUTTON
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={6}>
    BUTTON
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12}>
    BUTTON
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Where `xs={value}` defines how big a grid item should be.
So for your case you need two equal columns on top of one column that is the sum of the above columns.

Comment: Better, but you haven't really explained your solution. You should mention the changes you made. See [answer].